# Stopping interval at syntax error doen't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, intervals

I have built my own javascript console in a website! Pressing the GO - Button runs the following function, after comments are removed from the code:

```
var interv;

function go(code) {
    code  += "clearInterval(interv);";
    interv = setInterval(code,1);
}
```

My problem appears when calling very time-consuming functions or when there's a mistake in the code: it doesn't stop, sometimes even the browser crashes.

What have I done wrong? Or is there a better way to get the same result?

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8yk2/3/)** (it works best in Firefox)

PS: Maybe you like the spirograph function in this jsFiddle. It's similar to a function in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations) website, but better.

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval` at all here? If the code has an error, then `clearInterval(interv);` will  never be called.

Comment: You know, setInterval accepts a function as a first parameter, passing that as a string is much better. Also, you can use `setTimeout`

Comment: Are you just looking for `eval` ? Or the function constructor?

Comment: I just tried to run a _String from a textfield_ as a _javascript code_. This is the only way I actually know to do this. Or is there a better way?